# Is $U(c):=\{]a,b[~\mid ~]a,b[ \text{ is neighbourhood of } c \}$ a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$]a,b[$ is neighbourhood of $c \in \mathbb{R}$ if $c \in ]a,b[$.

Is $U(c):=\{]a,b[~\mid~]a,b[ \text{ is neighbourhood of } c \}$ a set?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes, it's a set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $\textbf{}$ $\textbf{}$ $\textbf{}$